# Java EE 6 and above, static resource in web fragments

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

let's say we have a  main web project P, and two web fragments A and B.
Both A and B have a test.html under META-INF/resources, when user visit /APPROOT/test.html, which one will be picked ? Does java ee define the rules about this?

I have readed this [blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment)

It's very useful, but it's just about the processing order of web fragments. I tested with tomcat 8, I define the order like this:

```
<absolute-ordering>
        <name>B</name>
        <others />
    </absolute-ordering>
```

but the test.html in web fragment A is still picked.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is defined in section 4.6 of the servlet 3.0 spec:

> 4.6 Resources The ServletContext interface provides direct access only to the hierarchy of static content documents that are part of the Web
>   application, including HTML, GIF, and JPEG files, via the following
>   methods of the ServletContext interface:
>
> - getResource
> - getResourceAsStream
>
> The getResource and getResourceAsStream methods take a String with a
>   leading “/” as an argument that gives the path of the resource
>   relative to the root of the context or relative to the
>   META-INF/resources directory of a JAR file inside the web
>   application’s WEB-INF/lib directory. These methods will first search
>   the root of the web application context for the requested resource
>   before looking at any of the JAR files in the WEB-INF/lib directory.
>   **The order in which the JAR files in the WEB-INF/lib directory are scanned is undefined.** This hierarchy of documents may exist in the
>   server’s file system, in a Web application archive file, on a remote
>   server, or at some other location.